# How to check if a certain property is present in select

Tags: jquery, html

I've this html select:

```
<select id="select-filter-item" data-hasqtip="true" title="" aria-describedby="qtip-3">
        <optgroup label="Servizi" type="services-group">
              <option type="provider">Tutti i trattamenti</option>
              <option value="13" type="service">Taglio</option>
              <option value="14" type="service">Colore</option>
        </optgroup>
</select>
```

How you can see I've the first option without value property, I want check if the current value selected from the `select` have the property `value` or not, if yes get the `value` number as 13 or 14. How I can achieve this?

I get the value like:

```
var po = $('#select-filter-item').val();
```

Comment: All `option` elements have a `value` property. As you have not defined it explicitly, it is set to the `innerText` of the element - in your case `Tutti i trattamenti`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pp5r2zau/

Comment: Okay thanks for the hint I don't know this. Anyway how I can check if the current value is a number or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to see if the value is numeric or not

```
$('#select-filter-item').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    var isNumber = val !='' && !isNaN(val );
    alert(isNumber);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var selected = $("#select-filter-item option:selected"), 
    val = $(selected).val();

if(val){ //this checks if the value is not falsy (0, undefined, null, "", false)
   if(typeof val === "string"){
      //do something with your string
   } else if(typeof val === "number") {
      //do something with your number
   }
}


/* You can also use jQuery instead of css selector 
   to go through a div tree, as far as I know it has better
   performance 
*/

//var selected = $("#select-filter-item").find("option:selected");
```

Comment: it's possible check if the value is a number or a string?

Comment: will always be string , also no need to look for selected, value will be the same using OP code `$('#select-filter-item').val();`

Comment: seems not working my val is "Tutti i trattamenti" and the string condition isn't fired